# Does dreaming have any physiological impact on our body?

Tags: physiology, dreaming

Personally speaking, when I wake up after a really good dream, I feel really happy, similar to how I would feel if something good has happened in reality. This makes me wonder if we are actually going through stress when we are having a nightmare. Is there an increase of epinephrine in our body when we dream about being in trouble or running away from a scary situation? Similarly, are endorphins released when we are experience a happy moment in our dreams?